# We have a Mint tag

Tags: discussion, tags, derivatives

We have a tag called [mint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mint), and one user [said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365085/straight-into-bios-after-starting-windows-8-on-asus-zenbook?noredirect=1#comment467140_365085) that it led him to believe that Mint questions are on topic, which they aren't. Is there *any* way in which this tag is useful or should we just delete it?

Comment: If a tag leads them to think they are on topic, then someone isn't writing the tag wiki/excerpt as they should.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since people actually use that tag it makes it easy for us to find topics about [mint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mint) >:-D

We also have a [fedora](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fedora) tag used 63 times. And [windows-7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), [windows-8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-8), [windows-xp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp) even [windows-phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone).

A Mint question could be valid if you have Ubuntu/Mint with Ubuntu/Mint in a VBox and there is a problem with the communication between the two. Or with a dual-boot setup.

As long as there is a relation with a supported Ubuntu operating system and secondly a relation with Mint it is valid. Solely Mint is not valid.

Comment: And it can also be used as a way to identify Mint-only questions and close them straightaway

Comment: I would suggest the tag be removed, because there is no way I can think of where both a) there is a situation that involved a partition with Min on it or something and b) *it is proper* to actually use the Mint tag.

Comment: I second @searchfgold6789